# Python not able to find patterns of chunk

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, chunks

I am trying to extract special chunks of POS tags like this and many chunks from
different patterns are working good and similar sentences can be found using them.But the problem rises when I see the exact sequence of tags I have defined in tagged words as output as chunk but the machine could not find them with the name I have defined.Example:

```
{<VB><RB.?><VB><NN.?>+<IN>*<JJ.?>*<NN.?>*}
```

This would easily find sentence of :

```
Do not take money from internal relations
```

But when I have another pattern:

```
{<IN><DT>*<NN.?>+<VBZ><RB.?>*<JJ.?><CC>*<PRP$><NN.?>+<VBZ><JJ.?><TO><VB><CC>*<VBG><PRP><MD><VB>}
```

for the example:
    if the present is not easy, or its size is difficult to quantify, but declining it would satisfy

It is not possible to detect it and shows it as a S only.Although I believe the pattern is exactly the same.Can this be because the clause I am looking for is sometimes in the beginning, sometimes in the middle and sometimes in the end of sentence?Can this be because I use I use PunktSentenceTokenizer?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure punctuation is ignored by the chunker? After all, they have a PoS tag of their own.

Comment: @lenz Yes that is not the problem.I removed the punctuation mark in the real text.

Comment: @lenz I found that the problem rises when you define more that one chunk group.more than one chunk patterns in one chunk group is fine, but if you want to add more chunk groups it does only detect one of the groups.

Comment: Good! Why don't you post your findings as an answer to your own question? This will help people with the same problem in the future.